# Mysql - Concat strings with accents cause malformed chars

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `providers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1392 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I try to contact `id` and `name` in a query:

```
SELECT id, name, CONCAT("[", id, "] ", name) AS value FROM providers;
```

It works great for most entries. However, when `name` has characters with accents, I get a malformed string:

```
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id  | name                    | value                   |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 138 | ÁREA TECNOLÓGICA        | [138] �REA TECNOL�GICA  |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Is there any way to fix it in the SQL level?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197634/how-to-fix-accented-character-substitutions-on-french-text-in-mysql-db

Comment: Well, that's when using `CONCATE` with int values

Comment: THanks @P.Salmon, unfortunately changing DB is not a possibility in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution, I leave it here in case it will help somebody:

When you try to concat different types, this is what happens.
So the solution is to use casting:

```
SELECT id, name, CONTACT("[", CONVERT(id, CHAR(8)), "] ", name) AS value 
FROM `providers`;
```

Comment: 'So the solution is to use csting' - csting??

Comment: @P.Salmon casting :)